# Как получить value из option на чистом JS?

Tags: javascript

Делаю блок калькулятора на чистом JS. Столкнулась с проблемой, что не могу получить значение value в option. Как вариант, получилось только через onchange в html, но знаю, что это костыль, поэтому интересует правильное решение.

```js
var select = document.getElementById('agriculture');

selectFunction = function() {
  var getValue = select.value;
  console.log(getValue);
}
```

```html
<select id="agriculture" onchange="selectFunction()">
  <option value="3100">Пшеница ≈ 3100 грн / т"</option>
  <option value="2500">Овес ≈ 2500 грн / т"</option>
  <option value="3100">Рожь ≈ 3100 грн / т"</option>
  <option value="2400">Кукуруза ≈ 2400 грн / т"</option>
  <option value="1850">Просо ≈ 1850 грн / т"</option>
</select>
```

Потом эти значения буду использовать в формуле.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Это не костыль, просто иногда бывает неудобно редактировать JS-функции в HTML. К тому же, где-то в другом месте кода если захочется добавить еще одно событие onchange на этот элемент, новый будет работать, а предыдущий - перестанет. В целом, полезнее использовать `addEventListener`

```js
var select = document.getElementById('agriculture');

select.addEventListener('change', function(){  
  var getValue = this.value;
  // this в этом контексте - элемент, который запустил фукнцию. То же, что и select.value;
  console.log( getValue );
});
```

```html
<select id="agriculture">
  <option value="3100">Пшеница ≈ 3100 грн / т"</option>
  <option value="2500">Овес ≈ 2500 грн / т"</option>
  <option value="3100">Рожь ≈ 3100 грн / т"</option>
  <option value="2400">Кукуруза ≈ 2400 грн / т"</option>
  <option value="1850">Просо ≈ 1850 грн / т"</option>
</select>
```

Comment: еще можно предложить вариант с `event.target` или `document.querySelector('#agriculture > option:checked').value`  :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью метода selectedIndex получить текущий индекс

```
var select = document.getElementById('agriculture');
var button = document.getElementById('buttonID');
```

`var selectedValue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;`
    `button.addEventListener('click',  event => console.log(selectedValue));`